# Can someone help? I want to do image classification using CNN while taking pose estimated as input

Tags: python, image-processing, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I hope you're all doing well.
I'm new here for help.  Basically, I have *hand poses* and *labeled data* for the **image**.
for example **image class** is labeled as:
1: Hold,
2: Pick up
3: Squeeze
.
.

So I need to use the **CNN model** for **image classification**.
I'm stuck in this task and looking for help.

Comment: Provide a good description of your problem ( code, structure, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I had updated my question above. Kindly have a look into it